# How did Dr. Paul Kersey wound his own left hand while shooting a pistol?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-wish-2018

In this clip from *Death Wish* (2018), Dr. Paul Kersey (played by Bruce Willis) can be seen firing at a pair of carjackers.

Notice that the two carjackers did not wound Willis's [web of the thumb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/364627). Dr. Kersey appears to have wounded his own web of the thumb, accidentally!

How? Did his pistol malfunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Slide Bite](https://mysisterskeeperdefense.com/blog/2018/1/18/avoiding-slide-bite#:%7E:text=The%20top%20half%20of%20the,(lower%20half%20of%20gun).).

A common injury for new or inexperienced gun users.

> It’s the same thing when a veteran shooter sees a novice gripping a semi-automatic handgun incorrectly by placing a portion of the hand behind and above the gun’s slide.You can see it coming from a mile away—usually from the other side of the plexiglass partition at the local gun range—but you rarely have time to stop it. Moments later the shooter fires and is frightened as he looks at his hand then shakes it while mouthing the word “Ouch!”
>
> He’s just received a [slide bite](https://www.nrafamily.org/articles/2020/8/6/how-to-avoid-slide-bite), which is a little cut on the web of the hand between the thumb and forefinger that’s caused by the sharp metal edge of the slide as it recoils rearward. Luckily, it’s not a bad injury—it’s like a nasty paper cut—but it does serve as a poignant reminder to always grip the gun properly even as the majority of your concentration is focused on the sights and target.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they even explained this in the movie.